# Replace value in html page with node.js

Tags: html, node.js, dynamic

I would liek to replace the value in a html page but it doesn't work:

```
     var Codice_HTML = data.toString;
 (*) replaceString(Codice_HTML,"valore_pm", "15")
     data.buffer= Codice_HTML;
     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     response.write(data);
```

If row (*) is uncommented page cannot be loaded.
The error says that `replaceString` wants `string` as input...

Comment: var Codice_HTML = data.toString()

Comment: Thanks Holger, but value not has changed in browser… :-(

Comment: data.buffer=replaceString(Codice_HTML,"valore_pm", "15")

Comment: thanks Jabird but gauge code in browser aways show "valore_pm" … :-(

Comment: var Codice_HTML = data.toString();
         var Codice_HTML=replaceString(Codice_HTML,"valore_pm", "15") ;
         response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
         response.write(Codice_HTML);

Comment: this code work..